# No me inicia la sesión en mi cuenta con las credenciales guardadas en mi Cookie PHP

Tags: php, session, cookies

Estoy tratando de guardar las credenciales de los usuarios en Cookies y ya eso lo he logrado, el problema es que estoy tratando de inicial sesión con esas credenciales guardad en Cookies, pero no me inicia la sesión.

```
// Mantener la sesion iniciada en el navegador
$userCookies = $_COOKIE["user"];
$passCookies = $_COOKIE["pass"];

echo $userCookies;

if(isset($userCookies)){

    // Inicial sesion con el email guardado en la cookies
    $sentencia = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$userCookies' AND password = '$passCookies'");

    $sentencia->execute(array(
        ':userCookies' => $userCookies
    ));

    $resultado = $sentencia->fetch();

    $email = $_SESSION['email'];
}
```

El correo y la contraseña se guarda correctamente en la Cookie, pero no se porque razón no me esta iniciando automáticamente la sesión cuando yo abro el navegador.

Mi objetivo es que cuando el usuario cierre el navegador, y este vuelva a abrirlo no tenga que inicial sesión nuevamente, si no que inicie la sesión con las credenciales guardadas en las Cookie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es posible que estes omitiendo el enviar la cookie al navegador no veo en tu codigo que uses [setcookie()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)

recuerda que el uso de cookies requiere que el navegador reciba la cookie, por lo que es un proceso de 3 pasos, 1.- el usuario entra con sus credenciales... 2.- se procesa y autentifica en tu script, donde generas la cookie (y la mandas) o generas un error... 3.- a partir de que enviaste la cookie, todas las llamadas subsecuentes llegaran con las cookies del usuario.

pero... ademas tienes un problema GRAVE de seguridad, NUNCA debes mandar como cookie un juego de credenciales (usr+psw), te recomiendo que solo mandes un dato (tal vez el ID encriptado del usuario) y que lo uses como llave para identificarlo.

Espero que esto te sirva de ayuda.

Comment: Es cierto, yo mismo pensado entre en razón de que es un error de seguridad enviar el email y el password a las cookie y por tal razón solo guardo el email del usuario, pero mi problema aun continua, no me esta iniciado la sesión automáticamente cuando el usuario abre el navegador. Ayúdame, mis usuario se están quejando porque tienen que inicial sesión cada vez que visitan la pagina

Comment: checando tu codigo, veo que tienes el prepare con DOS variables (usr y pass) y en el execute solo mandas el usuario, asegurate que el execute contiene la misma cantidad de parameteros que el prepare.